# Reinforcement Learning - How does an Agent know which action to pick?

Tags: machine-learning, policy, agent, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm trying to understand **Q-Learning**

The basic update formula:

```
Q(st, at) += a[rt+1, + d.max(Q(st+1, a)) - Q(st,at)]
```

I understand the formula, and what it does, but my question is:

**How does the agent know to choose Q(st, at)?**

I understand that an agent follows some policy π, but how do you create this policy in the first place?

- My agents are playing checkers, so I am focusing on model-free algorithms.
- All the agent knows is the current state it is in.
- I understand that *when* it performs an action, you update the utility, but how does it know to take that action in the first place.

**At the moment I have:**

- Check each move you could make from that state.
- Pick whichever move has the highest utility.
- Update the utility of the move made.

However, this doesnt really solve much, you still get stuck in local minimum/maximums.

So, just to round things off, my main question is:

How, for an agent that knows nothing and is using a model-free algorithm, do you generate an initial policy, so it know which action to take?

Comment: At the moment, I am just picking whichever action yields the highest utility, but I think this is the wrong to go about it since it heavily discourages exploration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That update formula incrementally computes the expected value of each action in every state. A greedy policy chooses always the highest valued action. This is the best policy when you have already learned the values. The most common policy for use during learning is the ε-greedy policy, which chooses the highest valued action with probability 1-ε, and a random action with probability ε.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I kind of had something like this already implemented but as quite worried I was missing something huge!

Comment: Even Google's Atari-playing AI uses reinforcement learning with an ε-greedy policy. It gradually decreases the ε from 1.0 to 0.1 over the first million frames while learning.